# Constructing a NOT statement to parse XML

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to construct a statement which will parse my XML looking for all rows which do not contain the words 'HIDE' or 'CANCELLED' in the 'Title' field and do not have a blank 'Indexed' field.

So far I have tried this as a starting point, which I thought would filter out everything containing 'HIDE' and an empty Indexed field, but it does not work.

```
$(xml).find("Qry1:not(Title:contains('HIDE'), Indexed:contains(''))").each(function(){
```

Am I even close to being right here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a sequential approach?

```
$(xml).find("Qry1")
    .not(":has(Title:contains('HIDE'))")
    .not(":has(Title:contains('CANCELLED'))")
    .not(":has(Indexed:empty)")
    .each( /* ... */);
```

Try it:

```js
var xml = "<root>\
  <Qry1>\
    <Title>HIDE</Title>\
    <Indexed>1</Indexed>\
  </Qry1>\
  <Qry1>\
    <Title>CANCELLED</Title>\
    <Indexed>1</Indexed>\
  </Qry1>\
  <Qry1>\
    <Title>I'm not indexed</Title>\
    <Indexed></Indexed>\
  </Qry1>\
  <Qry1>\
    <Title>Found Me!</Title>\
    <Indexed>1</Indexed>\
  </Qry1>\
</root>";

$(xml).find("Qry1")
    .not(":has(Title:contains('HIDE'))")
    .not(":has(Title:contains('CANCELLED'))")
    .not(":has(Indexed:empty)")
    .each(function () {
        var title = $(this).find("Title").text();
        $("<div>", {text: title}).appendTo("#target");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>
```

You could also use `.filter`, like this:

```
$(xml).find("Qry1")
    .filter(function () {
        var $this = $(this), 
            title = $this.find("Title").text(),
            indexed = $this.find("Indexed").text();

        return !(title === "HIDE" || title === "CANCELLED" || !indexed);
    })
    .each( /* ... */);
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do this. Would the .each part still be formatted as '.each(function()'?

Comment: My mistake, see changed answer with example.

Comment: Thanks for this! It works, however, I think I may have explained the logic wrong. I'm still getting rows which have an empty Indexed field. I think the code is fitering out the HIDE and the CANCELLED but still giving me rows that have an empty indexed field - how can I get rid of these too?

Comment: Wait, I think the problem is that when nothing is entered in my Indexed field it simply does not exist in the XML: how can I adjust for this?

Comment: I don't think using .not(':has(Indexed)') or !indexed will work because there are a number of possible entries which can be in the Indexed field, which is why I was trying to just filter out all the empty ones.

Comment: Try the alternative that uses `.filter`. It provides more flexibility.